# appengine: how can I check if a property from an entity exists in the datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I know it is not possible to query the datastore for missing values (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598605/appengine-query-datastore-for-records-with-missing-value)).

What about from python code? Is it possible to check if the value from an entity property comes from the datastore or from the default value?

Use case:

Model *Kind_X* has 1000 entities. For the property *Kind_X.my_property*.

- 500 entities do not have *my_property*
- 400 entities *my_property* is None
- 100 entities are other values

I would like to set *my_property* to *ABC* only for those 500 entities that do not have the property. The 400 entities that have the value None can not be modified.

Note: setting *my_property* default as *ABC* is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to introduce required property in GAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021752/how-to-introduce-required-property-in-gae)

Comment: if you dont understand the question you should not give a random answer nor mark it as duplicate...

Comment: not really, if you _want to make sure all the entities will show up as a result of a query_ as you commented , that answer is the way to do it. Oh, and probably it's you that you don't know what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.api import datastore

entity_key = 'ag1lbmdlbG1pbmFzd2VicgoLEgRVc2VyGGIM' 
entity = datastore.Get(entity_key)
print 'my_property' in entity
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all the entities of a given kind and check it programmatically with:

```
entities = Model.all()
for entity in entities :
  if not entity.newproperty :
    print "Hey, this entity is missing something"
```

If the number of entities is big, you should use the [mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) library to avoid timeout.

Comment: If you have nontrivial number stored, you'll timeout trying this. You need to do it in batches. You can roll your own batching using tasks, or use mapreduce, which has the batching built in.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this using the high-level `ext.db` framework. You could retrieve data using the lower level `google.appengine.api.datastore` framework (documentation is in the docstrings).

Why do you need to distinguish these two cases? It may be that there's a better approach.

Comment: I want to make sure all the entities will show up as a result of a query.

Comment: @schettino72 Then you should run a mapreduce or other procedure to retrieve and store every entity when you introduce the new property.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have lots of data you could do a map reduce and store the keys of the entities you want in a new model that only has a ListProperty holding the keys.
It's kind of a dirty hack and works only for less thatn 5k entities. It will also creates lots of metadata so be careful